# I want to split a string into array from 2nd element using Perl

Tags: perl, split

I have a string "sample.1.csv.main" want to split into array from 2nd element.

Here is the code I had tried

**Code** --

```
my $str = "sample.1.csv.main";
my @arra = split('\.',$str,2);

print "first element : $arr[0]";
```

**OUTPUT** :

first element : sample

**DESIRE OUTPUT :**

first element : sample.1

Answer (score 2):

Split on dots, then join the first two elements:

```
my $str = 'sample.1.csv.main';
my @arra = split /\./, $str;
splice @arra, 0, 2, join '.', @arra[0, 1];
```

See [join](http://p3rl.org/join) and [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice).

Answer (score 1):

I think no issues while doing like this:

```
my $str = "sample.1.csv.main";

my @arra = split('\.',$str);

print "first element : $arra[0].$arra[1]";
```